# How can I understand using of complex() function?

Tags: python

In python documentation it is wrote for built-in function complex([real[imag]]):

```
..or convert a string or number to a complex number.
```

But when I try:

```
>>> complex('string')
```

I get:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```

I don't understand something. I will be glad if someone tells me what is about?
Sorry if this question is simple, but i just start to learn python.

Comment: What complex number were you expecting to get back?

Comment: It's not Python you're misunderstanding, it's the concept of complex numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `complex` function is used for working with complex numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), of the form a+bj.  So you can use it like this:

```
>>> a = complex("1+2j")
>>> a
(1+2j)
>>> a*a
(-3+4j)
```

Answer (score 5):

`complex` is a data type for complex numbers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Examples on constructing them:

```
>>> complex(1, 2)
(1+2j)
>>> complex('1+2j')
(1+2j)
>>> complex(0)
0j
>>> complex(1)
(1+0j)
>>> complex(1) + complex(0, 1)
(1+1j)
```

If you aren't familiar with complex or imaginary numbers, you can probably just move on and not worry about any of this. =)

Comment: I will skip this but i will write something about this complex numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"string" isn't a complex number.  The proper usage is as follows:

```
>>> a = complex('3j')
>>> a
3j
>>> b = 4 + a
>>> b
(4+3j)
```

Answer (score 1):

'string' is not a number.  It's not anything like a number.

How can you compute a complex value of `string`?  It's not a number

Try using numbers or string representations of numbers

```
complex(2)
complex('3')
```

Comment: This is from documentation: "Create a complex number with the value real + imag*j or convert a string or number to a complex number."
But I thins it's mean that i can give number as a string, and because of that they wrote that it is possible to give string as paremeter.

Comment: @Cris: `'string'` is not a string representation of a number.  Why use a word that cannot possibly have a numeric value?  "give number as a string"  doesn't mean use the word `'string'`, does it?

Comment: So numbers can be string? For exapmple, is this a number and string "3"? Or I still don't understand.

Comment: @Cris: When you tried it, what did you observe?  Clearly `'string'` cannot possibly be a string value for a number.  It's a word.

Comment: Sorry if I am insistent. I know that 'string' is a word. Is it true that this word, "string" is in string format? And is it true that "3" is in string format? And is it true that difference betwen "strinh" and "3" is that the first one is word in string format and the secound one is number in string format?

Comment: @Cris: Yes. (1) Please read the Python language manual.  (2) Please try the two values, `'string'` and `'3'` with the `complex()` function and report back on what you actually observed when you actually typed actual code.

Comment: Just like i think complex('string') returns exception and complex('3') returns proper value. I thinks that I understand differences now but I will read documentation. I am reading now. Tahnk You.